# mysql2 gem does not like windows path with spaces

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, cmd

I am trying to install the mysql2 gem file and the path I have written is:

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySql Connector C 6.1.3`

`Error: Cannot find include dir at C:\Program/include`

It seems that the spaces in the path are interfering with the install.

How do I write the path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySql Connector C 6.1.3` without spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in quotes instead?

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySql Connector C 6.1.3"
```